# SQL Server: How to handle empty data found in xml node during select data from xml

Tags: sql-server, xml

Suppose my xml is stored in variable and I want to display xml data in tabular format. so this query i fired.

```
Declare @xml xml  

set @Xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitem>
  <Ticker />
  <TickerID />
  <TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValues>
    <TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValue>
      <TabName>xxxxxxxx</TabName>
      <StandardDate>2010 FY</StandardDate>
      <XFundCode>xxxxx</XFundCode>
      <BRTab></BRTab>
      <BRLineItem></BRLineItem>
      <StandardLineItem>aaaaa</StandardLineItem>
      <StandardValue>1608.7</StandardValue>
      <ActualProvidedByCompany>NO</ActualProvidedByCompany>
    </TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValue>
    <TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValue>
      <TabName>qqqqqqq</TabName>
      <StandardDate>3Q 2018</StandardDate>
      <XFundCode>RD_015</XFundCode>
      <BRTab></BRTab>
      <BRLineItem></BRLineItem>
      <StandardLineItem>ssssss</StandardLineItem>
      <StandardValue></StandardValue>
      <ActualProvidedByCompany>YES</ActualProvidedByCompany>
    </TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValue>
  </TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValues>
</TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitem>'

SELECT 
    x.Rec.query('./TabName').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'TabName',
    x.Rec.query('./StandardDate').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'StandardDate',
    x.Rec.query('./XFundCode').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'XFundCode',
    x.Rec.query('./BRTab').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'BRTab',
    x.Rec.query('./BRLineItem').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'BRLineItem',
    x.Rec.query('./StandardLineItem').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'StandardLineItem',
    x.Rec.query('./StandardValue').value('.', 'DECIMAL (18, 2)') AS 'StandardValue',
    x.Rec.query('./ActualProvidedByCompany').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'ActualProvidedByCompany'   
FROM @xml.nodes('/TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitem/TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValues/TickerBrokerStandardDateLineitemValue') as x(Rec)
```

As you can see the xml attribute `<StandardValue></StandardValue>` has no value in xml, but it is declared as decimal. So what kind of change do I need to add in my code so, that when `<StandardValue></StandardValue>` has no data then query will return 0.00 as the default value?

What kind of change should be there in this line `x.Rec.query('./StandardValue').value('.', 'DECIMAL (18, 2)') AS 'StandardValue',`

I tried this `nullif(0.0,x.Rec.query('./StandardValue').value('.', 'DECIMAL (18, 2)')) AS 'StandardValue',` but no luck and Error I got **`Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.`**

Please guide me. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<StandardValue></StandardValue>` (or `<StandardValue\>`) isn't the same as the node `StandardValue` not appearing in your XML. This means that, instead, the `StandardValue` node has the `varchar` value `''`. If a node doesn't have a value (`NULL`) then ideally don't include it in your data.

The `varchar` value `''` can't be converted to a numerical data type (try `CONVERT(int,'')` and `CONVERT(decimal(10,2),'')`), so you'll need to return the value as a `varchar`. Try instead using:

```
ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(decimal(10,2),x.Rec.query('./StandardValue/text()').value('.', 'varchar(11)')),0) AS StandardValue,
```

Notice that I've also added `text()`, as this is actually faster. I would suggest adding this to your other columns as well; especially if this query is against a (large) dataset rather than a variable.